# C sys/stat.h not every field of stat structure is initialised

Tags: c, linux, ls, stat

I have been trying to implement my own version of linux ls command recently. Everything works great, but when I try to use ls -l functionality, some fields of struct stat aren`t initialised - I get NULL pointers or garbage values, although it seems to happen only with certain files and directories, just as content of / and others, which belong to root, or root group. The fact I find strange is that writing permissions of the file is always successful. Here is the code of the faulty function:

```
void printFullList(struct dirent* pDirEnt) {
    struct stat fileStat;
    stat(pDirEnt->d_name, &fileStat);
    if(pDirEnt->d_type & DT_DIR)
        putchar('d');
    else 
        putchar('-');

    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' : '-');

    struct passwd *pwd;
    pwd = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
    struct group *gid = NULL; 
    gid = getgrgid(fileStat.st_gid);
    char date[15];
    strftime(date, 15, "%d-%m %H:%M", localtime(&(fileStat.st_ctime)));
    printf(" %d %s %s %5d %s %s\n", (int)fileStat.st_nlink, (pwd != NULL ? pwd->pw_name : "NO_PERM"), (gid != NULL ? gid->gr_name : "NO_PERM"), (int)fileStat.st_size, date, pDirEnt->d_name);
}
```

Thanks for help!

EDIT:

stat() returns -1. I set errno to 0 before every function call. I also print pDirEnt->d_name every time, as @chux adviced. Here`s the output for / :

```
mnt No such file or directory d---rw---- 16961624 root NO_PERM 1 27-03 08:13 mnt
usr No such file or directory d--x--x--- 16961648 root NO_PERM 1 27-03 08:13 usr 
root No such file or directory d--xr----- 16961672 root NO_PERM 1 27-03 08:13 root  
lost+found No such file or directory d-w------- 16961696 root NO_PERM 1 27-03 08:13 lost+found ...
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `stat()`. Maybe if you don't own a file, you can't `stat()` it…

Comment: Hmm, I checked errno and got:
No such file or directory
If ownership is the problem, could you tell any possible solution?
Running program as root doesn`t change anything. In most cases only one of user id and group id is unavailable.

Comment: 1) Insure `errno=0;` before `stat()` call.  Report `stat()` return value and `errno`.  3) debug idea: `puts(pDirEnt->d_name)` before `stat()` call.  Verify name and present working directory.

Comment: @daburu Don't post huge blocks of info in comments. Edit your original question to include the new useful information. No one wants to dig through all of the comments to try and find the relevant info.

Comment: I`ve just done it, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Passing pointer to struct dirent only was the problem: d_name field stores name of file whilst stat() function requires path to the file.
Now I pass file`s directory and dirent struct with its data and then merge them into path with:

```
int pathLength;
char path[PATH_MAX];
pathLength = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", directory, pDirEnt->d_name);
if(pathLength >= PATH_MAX)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Path was too long!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and then I do:

```
stat(path, &fileStat);
```

which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> stat() returns -1

When a system call returns an error indication, any data that you were expecting — like `fileStat` — can yield some valid data or pure garbage.

Compare the output of your program with `ls -l` and you'll see that the permissions and file sizes are nonsense.